# Dual booting windows and Ubuntu. Windows 7 wont load!

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I decided to dual boot Ubuntu 11.10 and windows 7, after i restarted it I did not get the choice between Windows and Ubuntu. So I downloaded Startup manager and realized that windows was not on it. so I check fdisk -l and got this

```
  Device Boot         Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *        2046    42000383    20999169    5  Extended
  Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
  /dev/sda5            2048    42000383    20999168   83  Linux
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to do to get windows started.

Answer (score 0):

there are no windows partitions, I think You erase windows partitions during ubuntu installations. 
How did You install dual boot with windows?
[image]